# Same website open in two different Google Chrome windows: can I set two different zoom levels?

Tags: google-chrome

The same URL is opened in two different Google Chrome windows: can I set two different zoom levels? By default, if I change the zoom level in one Google Chrome window, it will change the zoom level in the other Google Chrome window.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome, you can't open 2 different tabs (in a same window or in different windows) with 2 different zoom level.

However, there's an extension which might help you with this problem, called `Per Tab Zoom`. It allows you to zoom a tab without zooming the entire domain.